# Mollified solutions to an SDE

Tags: approximation, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have a Stochastic differential equation (SDE) as such
$$
dX_t = b(t, X_t)dt + \sigma(t, X_t) dW_t
$$
with $X_0 = x$ and $W_t$ being a Brownian motion. We futhere assume that $b$ and $\sigma$ are such that the solution to the SDE exists and it is unique a.e.

Conversely, if we mollify the differential equation; that is,
$$
   dY_t = b_\varepsilon(t, Y_t) dt + \sigma_\varepsilon(t, Y_t) dW_t
$$
with $b_\varepsilon(t,X_t) := (b \ast \eta_\varepsilon)(t, X_t)$ and similarly for $\sigma_\varepsilon$. Is it true that $Y_t = X_t \ast \eta_\varepsilon$? Or that $Y_t \to X_t$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ in $L^p_{\text{loc}}$ if $X \in L^p_{\text{loc}}$?
In general, there's some connection between the two SDE?

Comment: Can you describe what $\eta_\epsilon$ is here? And how is $b*\eta_\epsilon$ or $X_t*\eta_\epsilon$ defined? (I am aware that it is supposed to be a convolution, but how is the convolution done here exactly?)

Comment: In this case, assuming that $X_t$ and $t$ are one dimensional objects. Then, $\eta_\varepsilon(x,y)  = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} C\exp(-\varepsilon/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ for some $C > 0$ normalization parameter. Finally, the convolution can be defined as $$b \ast \eta_\varepsilon = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}  b(h_1, h_2) \eta_\varepsilon(x-h_1,y-h_2) \, dh_1 dh_2$$. And similarly for $X_t$ except the mollifier is ''projected'' to a single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning to $X_{t}* \eta_{\epsilon}$ because for each realization $X_{t}$ is only a function of $t$.  (But if you want, you could mollify the white noise i.e. $B_t=\int 1_{[0,t]}\xi(s)$ can be mollified as $B_t^{\epsilon}=\int 1_{[0,t]}\xi_{\epsilon}(s)$ for $\xi_{\epsilon}(s)=\int \phi_{\epsilon}(r-s)\xi(r)dr$).

The study of these approximations usually goes under the name of Wong-Zakai theorems "On the Convergence of Ordinary Integrals to Stochastic Integrals".

A good book reference is the Stroock-Varadhan book "Multidimensional Diffusion Processes" chapter on limit theorems 11.1.4 Theorem.

[image]

In terms of Lp-convergence see 11.4.2 Theorem.